# Visual Studio for Mac crashes with the following, what is the problem here?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-mac, .net-core-2.1

Since [Rider's debugging does not work always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673323/why-rider-says-a-variable-within-using-block-and-transaction-is-unknown-while-de) I wanted to try out Visual Studio for Mac and debug my code. But, as I open my solution, which consists of a Web Api project, multiple libraries and test projects, all of the .NET Core 2.1, VS for Mac crashes. I found this error in the logs, and I don't understand what is the problem here.

What I did so far:

- I created new solution with test project using VS for Mac, it can open it, build it without crash, opening my solution still causes crash
- I reinstalled it a few times, I tried to use stable, beta and alpha channels, but the result is the same

  > /Users/vsts/agent/2.140.2/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.VsTest/VsTestNamespaceTestGroup.cs:78
  >     at MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.VsTest.VsTestNamespaceTestGroup.AddTest (MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.VsTest.VsTestUnitTest) [0x000b3] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.140.2/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.VsTest/VsTestNamespaceTestGroup.cs:78
  >     at MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.VsTest.VsTestNamespaceTestGroup.AddTest (MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.VsTest.VsTestUnitTest) [0x000b3] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.140.2/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.VsTest/VsTestNamespaceTestGroup.cs:78
  >     at MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.VsTest.VsTestNamespaceTestGroup.AddTests (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable) [0x00023] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.140.2/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.VsTest/VsTestNamespaceTestGroup.cs:61
  >     at MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.VsTest.DiscoveredTests.BuildTestInfo (MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.VsTest.VsTestProjectTestSuite) [0x0002a] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.140.2/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.VsTest/DiscoveredTests.cs:52
  >     at MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.VsTest.VsTestProjectTestSuite/d__12.MoveNext () [0x0008e] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.140.2/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.VsTest/VsTestProjectTestSuite.cs:97
  >     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore/MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext (object) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1094
  >     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00071] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:961
  >     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:908
  >     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore/MoveNextRunner.Run () [0x00024] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1075
  >     at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.InvokeAction (object) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs:605
  >     at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback (System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,System.Threading.Tasks.Task&) [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs:632
  >     at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.Run (System.Threading.Tasks.Task,bool) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs:410
  >     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations () [0x000a3] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:3223
  >     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree () [0x0003c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2247
  >     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.TrySetResult (TResult_REF) [0x0004f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:433
  >     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.SetResult (TResult_REF) [0x0003d] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:608
  >     at MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.VsTest.VsTestDiscoveryAdapter/d__9.MoveNext () [0x00188] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.140.2/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting/MonoDevelop.UnitTesting.VsTest/VsTestDiscoveryAdapter.cs:112
  >     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore/MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext (object) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1094
  >     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00071] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:961
  >     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:908
  >     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore/MoveNextRunner.Run () [0x00024] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1075
  >     at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation/<>c.<.cctor>b__7_0 (object) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs:383
  >     at MonoDevelop.Ide.DispatchService/GtkSynchronizationContext/TimeoutProxy.HandlerInternal (intptr) [0x00014] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.140.2/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/DispatchService.cs:77
  >     at (wrapper native-to-managed) MonoDevelop.Ide.DispatchService/GtkSynchronizationContext/TimeoutProxy.HandlerInternal (intptr) [0x00021] in <465cec10a54c4988a5e59f3960c17ec0>:0
  >     at  <0xffffffff>
  >     at (wrapper managed-to-native) Gtk.Application.gtk_main () [0x00008] in <40f46e55eb67454ab904dc9e5644a3a1>:0
  >     at Gtk.Application.Run () [0x00001] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-06/external/bockbuild/builds/gtk-sharp-None/gtk/Application.cs:145
  >     at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeApp.Run () [0x00006] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.140.2/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/Ide.cs:464
  >     at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run (MonoDevelop.Ide.MonoDevelopOptions) [0x009d4] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.140.2/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/IdeStartup.cs:377
  >     at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Main (string[],MonoDevelop.Ide.Extensions.IdeCustomizer) [0x000b2] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.140.2/work/1/s/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/IdeStartup.cs:797
  >     at Xamarin.Startup.MainClass.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.140.2/work/1/s/md-addins/Xamarin.Startup/Main.cs:11
  >     at (wrapper runtime-invoke) .runtime_invoke_int_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00057] in :0

Comment: Great... at least I haven't paid for this machine... Other option would be change to java, but that is what I really don't want to do.

Comment: Well, i would change platform or programming language since it is just a tool to help you to achieve your goals. Go for java or python. If you like java libs then go for kotlin.

Comment: @AdamOstrožlík - your comment about it being a Mac doesn't make any sense. This is an issue specific to the OP's code in combination with the IDE. Telling someone to change OS or programming language isn't helpful.

Comment: @SayusiAndo - have you tried installing VSCode and opening your project? Do you have a specific need for Visual Studio for Mac?

Comment: I just got fed up wasting my time with poor tools and not debugging my code. VSCode will be the next. Can it manage solutions and debugging it like VS?

Comment: I’ll install a Win10 in virtualbox and move forward with my code.

Comment: Be sure that you have correctly net core SDK and Tools installed in your mac. I run .Net Core since 1.0 preview in my mac and working well with vs code and VS for mac

Comment: Rider can manage and compile my code. Dotnet command runs without problem, VS says everything is ok, but it crashes still.

Comment: Can I ask why my question is downvoted? What detail is missing, how can I make it better?

Comment: Here's someone else with this problem: https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/issues/5817 Doesn't look like a conclusive solution though

Comment: The crash looks like the stackoverflow bug that Lennart linked to. That bug has been fixed but not released yet. A workaround would be to create a new solution and add all the projects but not the test projects. Another workaround might be to disable the Unit Testing Core addin from the Extensions Manager.

Comment: FYI, the link at the top of the question is now broken.  Probably best to remove the reference to Rider from this question entirely; it doesn't add much to the question/problem statement.